# How to control FPS per window surface?

Tags: qt, qml, qtwayland

In my program, there are QtWaylandCompositor which contains two windows for each screen.

```
WaylandCompositor {
  WaylandOutput  {
     window: Window {
       id: screen1
     }
  }
  WaylandOutput  {
     window: Window {
       id: screen2
     }
  }
}
```

I want to control the maximum FPS of each window surface.
one screen performs max 30 FPS and another max 60 FPS.
So I am looking for a solution like `QT_QPA_UPDATE_IDLE_TIME` not for the process but the window.

---

> QPlatformWindow subclasses can re-implement this function to provide
> display refresh synchronized updates.

I am trying to reimplement `QPlatformWindow::requestUpdate` https://code.woboq.org/data/symbol.html?root=../qt5/&ref=_ZN15QPlatformWindow13requestUpdateEv,
but I don't know how to put the customized `QPlatformWindow` class into `QQuickWindow`.
https://code.woboq.org/qt5/qtbase/src/gui/kernel/qwindow.h.html#_ZNK7QWindow6handleEv